# Bootstrap Help - Responsive Menu Not Showing Up

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am doing a project for school where we are remaking a website for a trucking school.  I'm super duper new to bootstrap, and the issue I'm having is this.

When I resize the page, the main navigation disappears as it's supposed to but I can't get the little menu icon navigation to show up.  I tried all the things you are supposed to according to getbootstrap.com and several searches but nothing worked.  I think part of the problem may be that I did some kind of hacky stuff by splitting my nav area up into two containers so that the top part with the logo could be a different color than the lower part with the actual menu--without the hacky stuff either the menu or the header would have ended up with an unslightly margin on both sides.

So I'm not sure if the hacky thing I did is causing the problem, and if so, can I do something else to make the top of the nav bar a different color than the bottom without getting a different colored margin on the sides?  Or do I just need to do something different with the toggle code?

Here is the HTML in question (without the toggle code... I tried it in several places so I just took it out in hopes it would be easier to read):

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="backgroundBlack">
  <div class="container ">
    <div class="navbar-header ">
      <h1><img src="images/logo.png" alt="logo" />Carolina Trucking Academy</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" >
      <div class="container">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="careers.html">Careers in Trucking</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="classes.html">Our Classes</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="admissions.html">Admissions</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="about.html">About Us</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Any help would be appreciated!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to follow the structure that bootstrap has provided.  At smaller screens the nav is hidden and toggled with a button in the navbar-header.  First thing you are missing is that navbar-toggle button.  This button will target your navbar-collapse at mobile screens with the `data-target=""` attribute.  I have also added the navbar-default class to the navbar.  These are premade styles that bootstrap has put in place.  Also to get the 2 different background colors i have just added the black-bg class to the container in the navbar-header and then changed the navbar-header css to display block and a width of 100%.  If you want to change the color of the navbar-default just target that class in your css and the links section of your navbar will change the background color.  Also I have used container-fluid in the example for your containers.  You can change it to container if you want I just think it looks better with container fluid.

Here is how it probably should look:

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <div class="container-fluid black-bg">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logo</a>
        </div><!--/.container-fluid -->
      </div><!--/.navbar-header -->
      <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="careers.html">Careers in Trucking</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="classes.html">Our Classes</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="admissions.html">Admissions</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="about.html">About Us</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!--/.container-fluid -->
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </nav>
```

And the css for making your navbar black and your navbar-header to display at full widt, you can add your custom styles to these classes:

```
.navbar-default{
  border-radius: 0;
}
.navbar-header{
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
.black-bg{
  background: #000;
}
```

Here is a fiddle to show you this in action and how it will look [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wamosjk/t8j37jff/)